# Image View Double Border

Tags: ios, swift, border, calayer

I'm calling a function that sets up a UIImageView:

```
func setupImageView(_ imageView: UIImageView) {}
```

I want to give that UIImageView an image, round its corners, and give it two different borders.

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
imageView.image = imageConstants.imageThatIsWanted
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.height / 2
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

What is the best way to apply a second borderColor of color blue around the white border?

I tried creating a sublayer as a CALayer and giving it a blue border, but this goes behind the image, and also inside of the white border. I also tried drawing a UIBezierPath, but that stays inside of the white border as well.

Comment: Couldn't you make the image view be a subview of a larger `UIView`? One that is 6 points more in height/width, and it has a blue border?

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.size.height/2
         secondView.layer.cornerRadius = secondView.frame.size.height/2
        imgView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        imgView.clipsToBounds = true
         secondView.clipsToBounds = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add UIlabel or UIImageview at back of your image view having size little bit larger than your image view and applying corner radius, if you want to reduce line of your code (Please check below code)

```
imgview.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imgview.layer.cornerRadius = imgview.frame.size.width/2
    imgview.layer.borderWidth = 5
    imgview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

Add new image view programatically at back side of image view already taken

```
let img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: imgview.frame.origin.x - 2, y: imgview.frame.origin.y - 2, width: imgview.frame.size.width + 4, height: imgview.frame.size.height + 4))
    img.layer.masksToBounds = true
    img.layer.cornerRadius = img.frame.size.width/2
//img.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue // You can also use background color instead of border
img.layer.borderWidth = 5
    img.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    self.view.addSubview(img)
    self.view.sendSubview(toBack: img)
```

I know its not proper solution but we can use this to reduce lines of code
Hope it will helps you