# How to make double border lines in the UIImage with the Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimage, border

I have tried to look for the "double border" tricks in Swift to make like this. I have a feeling this could be like a "double border" in UIImage.

[image]

Let me know if you know the codes. :)

Comment: check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703742/image-view-double-border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take a UIView and add the UIImageView inside it.
Clear the color of the UIView to clear.

This is what I have done using the storyboard.

1. Added the UIView and a UIImageView inside it, the color of the view is set to clear and the image view is at 15 points from all the sides. Please change as per your requirement (Refer image 1).
2. This is the view controller code (Refer image 2).
3. Output(Refer image 3).

**Note** :Just a basic idea, though you can change the color and the borderwidth etc as per your requirement.

[Storyboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyejv.png)

[View controller code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBkjU.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uknIA.png)

Comment: That's very interesting! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You need to add borderColor(black) and cornerRadius to the default layer of UIImageView.
Along with this, you have to add another sublayer in UIImageView with borderColor as grey.

```
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.width / 2

let borderLayer = CALayer()
borderLayer.frame = imageView.bounds
borderLayer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
borderLayer.borderWidth = 14.0
borderLayer.cornerRadius = borderLayer.frame.width / 2
imageView.layer.insertSublayer(borderLayer, above: imageView.layer)
```

See the attached playground demo.
[image: See the attached playground sample]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add 1 circle (UIView) as a subview between UIImageView and UIImage. For example, you can initialise UIImageView with the `gray` color for the outer cornerRadius. Then, you add the circle UIView and finally the UIImage.

Or, the alternative can be adding the UIImage before the circle UIView (with transparent background).

I think you can found the similar code here: [Image View Double Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703742/image-view-double-border)

Comment: Adding a subLayer is efficient than adding a subView.